# How to test / mock the following:

Tags: javascript, reactjs, unit-testing, jestjs

here is what I have for **file.js**
How could I mock the following and perform a unit testing:
thanks

```
var dataset = document.getElementById('test') ? 
document.getElementById('test').dataset : {};
export const SERVICE_URL = 'http://localhost:/';
```

Using JEST / EZNYME  for REACTJS - something along these lines: **file.test.js**

```
const mockTrue = {SERVICE_URL};

describe ( " Service URL ", () =>{
 it ( ' should output ', () => {
expect(mockTrue).toBeCalled('http://localhost:xxxxxxx/');
});
```

Comment: I'm not sure exactly what you are trying to test here? that `SERVICE_URL === 'http://localhost:/'`?

Comment: Correct Ben - just as a simple example

Comment: you either mocking module to test something else or you test it. constants actually don't require testing - everything you can do is comparing actual value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Testing dataset**

You won't be able to test both branches of the ternary condition with the current implementation.

This is because the value for dataset will be resolved the moment you import it. It is not possible to perform operations later on to add an element with `id=test` and hope that the value gets updated.

In order to get 100% coverage on this, you have to export a function instead :

```
export function getDataSet(){
  return document.getElementById('test') 
    ? document.getElementById('test').dataset 
    : {};
}
```

which makes this testable.

**Testing SERVICE_URL**

As other fellows mentioned, you can't do any better than

```
expect(SERVICE_URL).toBe('http://localhost:/');
```

Testing constant values is just testing for the sake of it. Apart for ensuring this constant doesn't get modified without an "are you sure?" flag, this doesn't bring any value whatsoever.

**Some comments**

Achieving 100% test coverage is an utopy that lead to the development of brittle tests. This purism is doing you disservice.

If truly you want to get to this shiny 100%, it is preferable that you remove dummy code from test coverage.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, this should assert that your SERVICE_URL contains the value you expect:

```
describe ( " Service URL ", () =>{
    it ( ' should output ', () => {
        expect(SERVICE_URL).toBe('http://localhost:/');
    });
});
```

Comment: Test pass but i was wondering if theres a way to test the top line : var dataset = document.getElementById('test') ? document.getElementById('test').dataset : {};

Comment: What do you want to test about that line? That it finds an element with the id of 'test'?

Comment: when i try to do a npm test coverage - it shows that this line has not been tested. i was wondering if theres something that I could write to make sure its 100 % covered